# Dual screen reset after restart

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have an Xubuntu system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux tnick-desktop 3.5.0-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 11 18:51:59 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
Description:     Ubuntu 12.10
Release:         12.10
Codename:        quantal
```

with an Nvidia video card:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9500 GT] (rev a1)
```

When I first installed Xubuntu and Nvidia's current driver all went fine. I was able to use `nvidia-settings` to configure the monitors to show a side-by-side view, saved the `xorg.conf` file and everything worked fine.

Some days ago I was curious about **Settings Manager > Display section**. I went looking, did not change anything and that was that. However, ever since, when I restart the system the layout that is saved in `xorg.comf` is not applied, so each and every time I have to use `nvidia-settings`, lay them out side by side and apply this. I tried using

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

but that made no difference (not that I was expecting it to, but it was suggested in a question here).

I also tried

```
un-install - restart - install - restart - nvidia-settings, lay them out - restart
```

but that gave me black screens after Xubuntu logo, then, on third attempt, went back to same view on both displays.

The content of the `xorg.conf` file does not change between sessions:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 304.51  (buildd@batsu)  Fri Oct 12 12:53:54 UTC 2012

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics L1942"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 9500 GT"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I tried to install Nvidia binary X.Org driver (version 173) but ended up in an error pretty soon:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

nvidia-173: Depends: x11-common (>= 1:7.0.0) but 1:7.7+1ubuntu4 is to
be installed
            Depends: xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.10.99.901) but 2:1.13.0-0ubuntu6.1 is to be installed
```

with an **Crash report detected** message.

Apart from reinstalling the system, what else should I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand, the way Ubuntu reads `xorg.conf` has changed in recent releases. What worked for me was to put a "good" `xorg.conf` file into

`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

and reboot or log out and back in.

I still haven't figured it out entirely, but I believe that upon startup, Ubuntu  looks there for any X setting overrides. Having an entire `xorg.conf` file there is probably not the idea, but it worked for me.

I believe that the problem is, that the settings managers from Nvidia or Ati save their changes to `/etc/xorg.conf` but Ubuntu does not update any of its own files dynamically... something like that.

Sorry if this is not a scientifically correct solution, but I believe it could be a work-around or at least give you some pointers for further investigation.

DrTebi

Comment: DrTebi, thank you for your answer. Indeed, it has solved my problem (if is a hack or not is not a concern for me). Also, thank you for registering an account just for responding to my question. :)

Comment: Important note for Xfce-users: make sure to delete `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml` if it is present, as this overwrites the `xorg.conf` settings but is itself not working correctly (at least for me with Xubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I was having this problem with Xubuntu 12.04, and none of the fixes for Nvidia Xserver did the trick. I ensured I ran `nvidia-settings` as `root`, regenerated `xorg.conf`, changed the `xinit` files, edited `xorg.conf` manually (using `"TwinViewOrientation"` in every imaginable way, as well as playing with the offsets). I reinstalled the driver twice (and somehow managed to lock my user account out in the process?) and re did all of the aformentioned fixes. I pretty much tried everything I could find by searching for problems with Nvidia Xserver dual monitor and persistent settings.

In the end, moderately hungover me approached the problem from a different angle: I just searched for other ways to use dual monitors in Xubuntu. ["How to use multiple monitors in Xubuntu"](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/how-to-use-multiple-monitors-in-xubuntu.html) did the trick for me. Basically I installed what it said and generated the script for use in startup applications, completely side-stepping the `nvidia-settings` and `xorg.conf` trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm not really a man of faith but on this matter I prefer a cautioned approach: I won't touch it before it's broken again, :)) I'm sure your answer will help some frustrated soul out there...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please avoid posting the same answer in more than one place. When tempted to do so, this typically means: (1) the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), (3) the answer should really be a comment, **or** (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.